# Filter pivot table using 2 cell values

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, pivot-table

I'm trying to filter a pivot table based on two cell values for two different filters. I have found code I'm able to adapt for one of the cells I have, I'm unsure how to go about integrate a second one which is in the cell below (See code I'm adapting below)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'H6 or H7 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Category")
NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H6").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After further thought I figured my problem out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'H6 or H7 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field1 As PivotField
Dim Field2 As PivotField
Dim NewCat1 As String
Dim NewCat2 As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field1 = pt.PivotFields("Category1")
Set Field1 = pt.PivotFields("Category2")
NewCat1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H6").Value
NewCat2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H7").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field1.ClearAllFilters
Field1.CurrentPage = NewCat1
Field2.ClearAllFilters
Field2.CurrentPage = NewCat2
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```